# D7 - Syntax of js custom file added directly to theme

Tags: theming, javascript

Alright, so I've read the documentation of JS framework in Drupal and there is a simple example how the syntax of JS file should look:

```
Drupal.behaviors.myModuleBehavior = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $('input.myCustomBehavior', context).once('myCustomBehavior', function () {

    });
  }
};
```

I can't figure out what should I put instead of "myModuleBehavior" when js file is added directly to theme, not by custom module. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just needs to be unique (otherwise you'll overwrite something existing, this is JS after all). So it would make sense to go with

```
Drupal.behaviors.myThemeBehavior = {
```

But it doesn't really matter as long you're not elbowing an existing behaviour out of the way.

Comment: Everything's simple when you know ;)